# How to use Sublime Text's "Find in Files" to find files containing multiple different strings?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have `string1` and `string2` and a bunch of text files in a folder. The files may contain any number of occurrences of `string1` or `string2`.

Is there a way to use Sublime Text's "Find in Files..." utility to find all files containing **at least one** occurrence of **each**?

Looking into the subject I've been able to find a way to search for the [*or* of multiple strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689180/search-for-multiple-strings-in-several-files-with-sublime-3) (i.e. matching either matches the entire file), but what I'm trying to do is an *and*. On the other hand using non-consuming regular expressions as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/469951/1829518) simply doesn't seem to work in Sublime Text 2 (always yields zero matches).

Comment: Use alternation: `string1|string2`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is an example of something I'm not looking for. I even put it right there in the question (first link).

Comment: Then you should remove the *at least one occurrence of each*, it is misleading. You need `(?s)string1.*string2|string2.*string1` or `(?s)^(?=.*string1)(?=.*string2)`.

Comment: I thought emphasizing 'each' in bold separately from the 'at least one' made it clear. I'll try to think of a way to re-phrease.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This RegEx pattern will enable you to find files which contain each of your string queries:
`(string1[\s\S]*string2)|(string2[\s\S]*string1)`

`[\s\S]*` is used to match any character ( including line breaks ) as many times as necessary until the following set of characters is found.

[image: Multiple Query RegEx Pattern]

Comment: `[\s\S]*?` will further improve search efficiency by using the first instance of the following set of characters ( as opposed to the final instance, if `?` is omitted ).