# Search for multiple strings in several files with Sublime 3 using AND

Tags: regex, search, sublimetext3, sublimetext

This previous (similar) question of mine [Search for multiple strings in several files with Sublime 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25689180/1391441) was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31171687/1391441) with a way to search for multiple strings in multiple files in SublimeText, using the regex `OR` operator:

```
Find: (string1|string2)
Where: <open folders>
```

This works perfectly for searching files where *either* `string1` OR `string2` is present. What I need now is to search in lots of files for *both strings present*. I.e., I need to use the `AND` operator.

I looked around this question [Regular Expressions: Is there an AND operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/469913/1391441) and also this one [Regex AND operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3041320/1391441) and came up with the following recipes:

```
(?=string1)(?=string2)
(?=.*string1)(?=.*string2)
(string1 string2)
(string1\&string2)
```

but none of them work.

So the question is: how can I search multiple strings in several files at once with SublimeText?

(I'm using SublimeText 3103)

**Add**: *the strings are not necessarily in the same line*. They can be located anywhere within each file. For example, this file:

```
string1 dfgdfg d dfgdf

sadasd
asdasd

dfgdfg string2 dfgdfg
```

should trigger a match.

Comment: actually it was the previous match that was highlighting..its not working for me either..its only finding in the current file

Comment: Press `Shift+Ctrl+F` and enter the regex.. It is finding correctly in there

Comment: Which regex? What files are you using to test this?

Comment: `(?=.*string1)(?=.*string2)` regex..on pressing `Shift+Ctrl+F` you will get add folder option..add the folder containing all files..all the matches along with filepath will be displayed in a file

Comment: sublime may `crash` if there are too many files

Comment: As I said previously, that regex returns zero matches in my case, so it is not doing what I need. I don't know what files you are using where it works. You'd need to share them so I can see.

Comment: @rock321987 you shouldn't have deleted your answer, it was a good one. Just not the particular answer for this question, but a good one nonetheless.

Comment: use `(?=[\s\S]*string1)(?=[\s\S]*string2)[\s\S]+` regex..it works but is killing the sublime for too many files

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Open sublime Text and press

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

or click on the `Find in Files` options under `Files` tab. The above is keyboard shortcut for this option. When you press above key, these are following options

[image]

When you select <kbd>...</kbd> button from above, you get 6 options which are `Add Folder` or `Add Open Files` or `Add Open Folders`

## To search strings that occur in the same line

Use the following regex for your `and` operation

```
(?=.*string1)(?=.*string2)
```

I am using the following regex

```
(?=.*def)(?=.*s)\w+ <-- \w+ will help in understanding which line is matched(will see later)
```

and I am searching within `current open files`

[image]

Make sure the `Use Buffer` option is enabled (one just before `Find`). It will display the matches in a new file. Also make sure the `Show Context` (one just before `Use Buffer`) option is enabled. This will display the exact line that matches. Now Click on `Find` on the right side.

Here is the output I am getting

[image]

See the difference in background color of line `1315` and `1316`(appearing in left side). `1316` is matched line in `designation` file

This is the image of last part

[image]

There were total 6 files that were opened while I used this regex

## For finding strings anywhere in file

Use

```
(?=[\s\S]*string1)(?=[\s\S]*string2)[\s\S]+
```

but it will kill sublime if number of lines increases.

If there are only two words that you need to find, the following will work super fast in comparison to above

```
(\bstring1\b[\S\s]*\bstring2\b)|(\bstring2\b[\S\s]*\bstring1\b)
```

Comment: Which two strings are you searching for with the regex `(?=.*def)(?=.*s)`?

Comment: @Gabriel yes, I am searching for string `def` and string `s`

Comment: Try searching for `(?=.*string1)(?=.*string2)` in the following mock file http://pastebin.com/Tq6YJUfC It will not work and it should. I'm not sure what your line does, but it is not what I need.

Comment: @Gabriel it is finding line by line in the file..i.e. string1 and string2 both should be in same line

Comment: Well that's it then, I'm not after strings that are *in the same line*. They could be located anywhere within each file.

Comment: Those last two commands are great, thank you! Could you add the commands to perform the same search but *not* display such large chunks of file where the strings were found?

Comment: @Gabriel I don't understand why using `and`(2nd last regex) does not display the results in all currently opened file. The last regex displays all the matched lines. I am not sure about line numbers if it can be displayed for matched lines

Comment: I don't understand your cmmnt. Both last commands work great, and the last one is indeed faster. The only issue I find is that it displays large chunks of each file matched, and I like to get as little as possible, perhaps only the matched file's title.

Comment: @Gabriel I am sorry but I don't know (if there is) any way to display the file names. I will try to find it out