# Sublime Text 3 - Truncate search result file paths to project root

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext

When performing a global search in Sublime - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> -  search results returned include the entire file path:

```
/Users/Picard/Documents/my-app/views/partials/links.html.erb:
...
...
```

Is it possible for the file paths returned in search results to reflect the project root (`path` in `.sublime-project`)?

For example, assuming `my-app` was my project's `path`, can results be returned as:

```
 /views/partials/links.html.erb:
 ...
 ...
```

I have already tried including`<project>` in "Where" field as seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20519244/2144912.